# AJAX with POST and PHP returning plain text- apache configuration?

Tags: php, ajax, forms, apache, post

I'm having trouble using POST with Ajax and then processing with PHP.

I'm currently working through this example and adapting it to fit my needs:
http://coursesweb.net/ajax/ajax-post-php

I've copied the 2 example files exactly, and when i submit the form the browser simply displays the text content of the PHP file.

The demo at the bottom of that page is working fine, so I assume there must be something wrong with my server configuration? (Apache 2.2.22 with PHP 5.3.16)

Standard Ajax requests are working correctly, as is a normal PHP Post form, the problem is only when using Ajax to post.

Any help would be awesome!

if you dont want to click the link:
test_form.php

```
<?php
// if data are received via POST
if (isset($_POST['nume']) && isset($_POST['mesaj'])) {
  // get data into variables, deleting the html tags
  $nume = strip_tags($_POST['nume']);
  $mesaj = strip_tags($_POST['mesaj']);

  // if the form fields are completed
  if (strlen($nume)>0 && strlen($mesaj)>0) {
    echo 'Welcome <b>'. $nume. '</b><br />The message you`ve sent: <pre>'. $mesaj. '</pre>';
  }
  else {
    echo 'Fill in all form fields';
  }
}
?>
```

ajax_form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" />
<title>Example Ajax and Form</title>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
// create the XMLHttpRequest object, according browser
function get_XmlHttp() {
  // create the variable that will contain the instance of the XMLHttpRequest object (initially with null value)
  var xmlHttp = null;

  if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {       // for Forefox, IE7+, Opera, Safari, ...
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else if(window.ActiveXObject) {   // for Internet Explorer 5 or 6
    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  return xmlHttp;
}

// sends data to a php file, via POST, and displays the received answer
function ajaxrequest(php_file, tagID) {
  var request =  get_XmlHttp();     // calls the function for the XMLHttpRequest instance

  // gets data from form fields, using their ID
  var nume = document.getElementById('nume').value;
  var mesaj = document.getElementById('mesaj').value;

  // create pairs index=value with data that must be sent to server
  var  the_data = 'nume='+nume+'&mesaj='+mesaj;

  request.open("POST", php_file, true);         // sets the request

  // adds a header to tell the PHP script to recognize the data as is sent via POST
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  request.send(the_data);       // sends the request

  // Check request status
  // If the response is received completely, will be transferred to the HTML tag with tagID
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      document.getElementById(tagID).innerHTML = request.responseText;
    }
  }
}
--></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="resp">Here will be displayed the server response.</div><br />
<form action="test_form.php" method="post" name="form1" onsubmit="ajaxrequest('test_form.php', 'resp'); return false;">
  Your name: <input type="text" name="nume" id="nume" size="20" maxlength="33" /><br />
  Your message:<br />
  <textarea name="mesaj" id="mesaj" cols="25" rows="4"></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code above works fine for me, must be something on your server. Are those the actual codes you're using?

Answer (score 1):

I feel stupid... but I figured it out.
The post request will only work if you open the html page from localhost. I was opening it using the file path.

Answer (score -1):

If the browser is showing you the PHP source, then it isn't processing the request through PHP at all. This is either an Apache misconfiguration (most likely) or the PHP file is misnamed (Apache uses the filename to determine when it should pass through the PHP module.) If the file is named correctly, check your Apache configuration; you said that some PHP files are working, so it may be that the directory or vhost that the non-working PHP file resides in is not configured to use mod_php.